# Best Tutorials for Flex+Android mobile application

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile-application

Im worked with flex4 for web applications. Now I am interested with developing mobile applications with flex+android,Can any one provide me the links for Tutorials which will usefull for beginners? I find many on Google but I dint find good tutorials for for beginners
can anyone help me how to step forward?

Comment: if you got the answer, please mark the correct one accepted

Comment: @manu I know... Did you refer Bill Karwins answer for that question?(last answer)

Comment: @manu pls try it once more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using Flash Builder 4.5 to package applications for Google Android devices](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html)

[Adobe Flex on Android](http://blogs.adobe.com/koestler/2010/08/adobe-flex-on-android.html)

[Sample Application using Flex and AIR for Android](http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/05/sample-application-using-flex-and-air-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

go to wowebook.net and search for mobility they show tou some tutorials that is flex with android or iphone arround 4 gb data.

I have found many flex with android or iphone video's there only i am confortable with them.

Comment: +1 Nice link provided very informative..